# Could NSAIDs lift bilirubin level?

Tags: blood-tests, nsaids-pain-meds, bilirubin

If one takes 800 to 1200 mg of ibuprofen a day for 3 to 4 weeks, could that lift total bilirubin level to around 28 micromole/litre and direct bilirubin to around 8 micromole/litre?

Comment: Not that common, but still it can be: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK547845/. What's the level of liver enzymes? (AST, ALT, GGT, ALP).

Comment: All within normal range.

Comment: What about the previous blood test before taking this medicine? (indirect bilirubin was normal then?)

Comment: It has never been measured before.

Comment: Then probably this patient has Gilbert syndrome (the direct bilirubin also slightly increase in it).